# Is it a "driver license" or a "driver's license" or a "drivers license" or...what?

Tags: phrases, word-usage

I've often wondered why my Ohio license is called a "driver license". It is awkward to say it like that.

Wouldn't something like driver's license be more appropriate?

Or driving license (like hunting license)?

[image: results from the almighty google]

(Note: image above shows `driver`, `driver's`, and `drivers` variations.)

Comment: Questions with pictures, automatic +1, but what's with the babies?

Comment: @callithumpian I don't know--that's just what came up in Google when I searched for `driver license`. Maybe people think they're cute so they share them

Comment: Hahaha! Nice one, didn't see it until @Callithumpian pointed it out!\

Comment: @Callithumpian: to say nothing of the vulgar gesture being made by the Ontario tyke...

Comment: The image does not reflect a proper ontario licence.

Comment: @Incognito the google search wasn't meant to be representative

Comment: Interesting that no one all those years ago pointed out that "driver" in "driver license" is a perfectly grammatical attributive noun.

Answer (score 13):

*New Oxford American* has this:

> **driver's license** |ˈdraɪvərz ˈˈlaɪsns|
>   *noun*
>   a document permitting a person to drive a motor vehicle.
>   **driving licence**
>   *noun*
>   British term for driver's license .

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard "driving license" here in the US.

Comment: and yet my license (and most of those in the image) say "driver license"...

Comment: In New South Wales, Australia - it's "Driver Licence".

Comment: In India subcontinent it's called "Driving Licence"

Comment: NSW Australia here too: yep, to my surprise, my licence card has "Driver Licence" on it, even though I've never heard anyone say anything but "Driver's Licence".

Answer (score 8):

Actually, try reading it like this:

> Licence of Driver.

I don't think there's anything wrong with it, although we *would* be more comfortable saying "driver's" or "driving"

"Driver" is just describing *what* kind of a license it is, not *whose*. Other examples would be "bar-tender license" not "bar-tender's license"

Comment: But when you talk about a restaurant license, you talk about a, well, restaurant license, not a restaurant's license. Whereas if you're talking about a driver's license, you almost always use the possessive. So this can't be the difference.

Comment: Agreed.  I had to look at mine (Connecticut, USA) to discover what it said; I've always used "driver's" conversationally, and it took me by surprise.  When I thought it through, this is the answer I came up with also.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that the name of the document is prescribed by law. The name is just whatever was chosen when the legislation was written.

Comment: ok, so if a legislator asked what he or she should write, what would you advise?

Comment: I would advise *driver's license* because it makes the most sense grammatically. It literally means "license of (some unspecified) driver." Phrases that use the possessive similarly that come to mind are *swimmer's ear* and *plumber's grease*. *Driving license* also makes sense, but sounds more British to me.

Comment: @Michael Haren: Fortunately, an unlikely situation to arise, given the spread of requirements for licences to drive motor vehicles.

Answer (score -4):

Using of driver/ driver's or driving license depends very much on what we are trying to say:

For example I would say:
a. I lost my driving license.
b. It was about a driver license.
c. I renewed my driver's license. (Provided that it is clear that I am talking about my driver's driving license.)

But again, in daily conversations, they are used almost interchangeably thus causing such confusions.

Comment: What region are you from? I live in New England, and everyone I know would use the phrase "driver's license" in all of those situations. I don't think I have ever heard anyone say "driving license" or "driver license."